# Symbolic matrix tensor an identity without specifying the dimension?

Tags: symbolic, tensors

I want to calculate an expression like $\left( M_1\otimes I+I\otimes M_2 \right) ^l$ with $M_i$'s symbolic matrices and $I$ the identity matrix with Mathematica. $M_i$'s are of the same dimension and my problem is how can I realize such an identity matrix without specifying the dimension of it, it should just work like a matrix multiply any matrix will still be the matrix itself(although it should be the same dimension as all the $M_i$)? Or is there some method that I can specify the dimension of the symbolic matrix $M_i$?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: After seeing the final edit, you can do something [**`like this`**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QREpa.png) I guess. I forgot the exponent, but you get the general idea I think

Comment: @bmf Thanks very much. I mean, is there some method that I can do not see the component of the matrix? For example, for $\left( M_1\otimes I+I\otimes M_2 \right) ^2$, the result I hope to see is $M_{1}^{2}\otimes I+I\otimes M_{2}^{2}+2M_1\otimes M_2$.

Comment: I guess you could try some global assumptions on the matrices and then do `MatrixPower` and `TensorExpand` or their cousins, but I have not managed to make it work.

Answer (score 2):

I think you can use [`KroneckerProduct`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/KroneckerProduct) and [`TensorExpand`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TensorExpand). Define:

```
e = KroneckerProduct[M1, IdentityMatrix[d]] + KroneckerProduct[IdentityMatrix[d], M2];
```

Then:

```
TensorExpand[e . e, Assumptions -> (M1|M2) ∈ Matrices[{d, d}]]
```

> 2 KroneckerProduct[M1, M2] +
> KroneckerProduct[IdentityMatrix[d], MatrixPower[M2, 2]] +
> KroneckerProduct[MatrixPower[M1, 2], IdentityMatrix[d]]

Comment: What about `MatrixPower[e,l]`?

Comment: @narip Can you be more specific about your question? Is it that you want to see `M1 . M1` instead of `MatrixPower[M1, 2]`?

Comment: Oh, thanks. I mean, if I want to see `e.e.e` or more `e.e.e.e`, how can I do this? I try `MatrixPower[e,3]`, but the result of Mathematica also contains `MatrixPower[e,3]`.

Answer (score 1):

Note that the symbol "[CircleTimes]" has not predefined meaning.Therefore, the terms are algebraically simply treated as one object.  Further, "I" has built in meaning of Sqrt[-1], do not use it for a variable name. Therefore, by writing e.g.:

```
(M1⊗II + II⊗M2)^2 // Expand
```

you get:

[image]

However, to get your expected result, you assume some properties that you did not declare.